# What is the typical sink water supply line size in San Jose del Cabo Mexico?

Tags: plumbing

What is the most common under-the-sink WATER SUPPLY LINE SIZE in San Jose del Cabo Mexico? Most plumbing goes by American standards. If no one answers I'll just make repeated trips with the old tubing to their local Home Depot and they will know. Thanks.

Comment: One trip yielding several size options seems like a wiser approach. Return policies are liberal.

Comment: Why not measure what you have before going to the store - just because they have a returns policy does not stop you using an inches stick.